# extracting numerical information from strings in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen this done in excel but I'd like to split the `SOP` and number into different columns. It gets a little tricky since the formatting is different at times.

```
0   SOP-015641
1   SOP-007809
2   SOP018262
3   SOP-007802
4   SOP-007804
5   SOP-007807
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [.str.extract()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method:

```
In [8]: df[['a','b']] = df.pop('col').str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)', expand=True)

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
      a       b
0  SOP-  015641
1  SOP-  007809
2   SOP  018262
3  SOP-  007802
4  SOP-  007804
5  SOP-  007807
```

[RegEx explained](https://regex101.com/r/pGsC5b/1)

Comment: This works great, thanks. Can you example the inputs within the extract function? Just for learning purposes.